# Python threading.Thread join() (inside class)

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность

Не могу найти, возможно ли заджойнить тред изнутри класса-наследника threading.Thread

```
import threading, time

class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        # threading.Thread.join(self) - не работает
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print('ONE')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mt = MyThread()
    mt.start()
    # mt.join() - так не интересно
    print('TWO')
```

Answer (score 0):

Не надо ничего джойнить, когда закончится метод `run`, поток закончится автоматически:

```
    # ...
    #mt.join() #- так не интересно
    print(mt.is_alive())
    while mt.is_alive():
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print('Waiting...')
    print('TWO')
    print(mt.is_alive())
```

Вывод:

```
True
Waiting...
ONE
Waiting...
TWO
False
```

Хотите закончить тред раньше - делаете досрочный `return` из метода `run` и тред закончится.

`join` треда-потомка - это как-раз способ не делать паузы, пытаясь угадать, когда же поток закончится, а грамотно дождаться в точности этого момента.

Изнутри же потока `join` просто не имеет смысла - он нужен чтобы ждать, когда закончится поток-потомок, в самом потоке вы просто заканчиваете работу - и всё, "рабочее место убрано", без всякой дополнительной магии.

**Update:** Если не хотите явно ждать в родительском треде и не хотите использовать, например, `async/await`, то можно просто в потомке бросить исключение, а в родителе его поймать:

```
    def run(self):
        print('ONE')
        time.sleep(5)
        raise Exception()
        sleep(1000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mt = MyThread()
    mt.start()
    #mt.join() #- так не интересно
    try:
        sleep(100) # здесь какая-то работа, которую нужно прервать из потомка
    except:
        print('Thread aborted!')
    print('TWO')
    mt.join()
```

Comment: Спасибо. Но интерес именно в том как из потомка заставить родителя ждать своего завершения

Comment: @AntonRyabenko Не понимаю, что значит "заставить ждать"? Вы хотите, чтобы родитель вдруг остановился в произвольном месте, когда сам потомок этого захочет и ждал, пока потомок завершится? Ну, это совсем другая задача получается. Можно попробовать что-то придумать, но вы сформулируйте сначала чётко, что вы хотите.

Comment: да, именно так, сказать родителю чтобы подождал
и именно внутри метода run треда-потомка

Comment: @AntonRyabenko В произвольный момент или чтобы родитель хоть сколько-то мог контролировать процесс? Можно просемафорить родителю, например.

Comment: в момент:

# threading.Thread.join(self) - не работает

Comment: @AntonRyabenko Ну можно бросить исключение, как я уже даже код написал )